# Understanding the performance behavior of numpy.reshape

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a problem where [`np.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) is a bottleneck. I want to understand in which situations it is fast and when it is slow. The following code exemplifies my question:

```
import time
import numpy as np
n = 28

# perm = np.arange(n)[::-1] #very slow
# perm = (np.arange(n)+15)%n #still slow
perm = (np.arange(n)+1)%n #fast


test = np.arange(2**n, dtype = np.complex64)

start_time = time.time()
test = test.reshape(n*[2])
test = np.moveaxis(test, np.arange(n), perm)
test = test.reshape(2**n)
print(time.time()-start_time)
```

Does anyone know where the C source-code for the reshape operation can be found?

Comment: Do you mean that `perm = np.arange(n)[::-1]` by itself is slow, or that `test.reshape(n*[2])` becomes slow when defining `perm` as such?

Comment: Source code for [`reshape`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/39bc1b1fb1024929e67aa9aad295fb9ec5d11ec4/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c#L181).

Comment: If it can return a `view` it is fast.  If it has to make a copy, it will be slower (but no slower than `.copy()`).  Check the `.base` of the result,  After some sort of `transpose` or certain slices, it will have to make a copy.

Comment: With `2**28` you have a large array, reshaped to 28d.  The `moveaxis` will be fast.  But the following reshape has to make a copy.  I'd have to look in more detail to deduce why the last perm is  faster.  To study it I'd choose `n` much smaller, and look at things like strides.  Using `complex` just makes the arrays larger, and doesn't add insight.

Comment: @jared, turns out all `perm` produce a `copy` upon `ravel`.  It's just that some copies  take longer than others.  I suspect it comes down to meory access times, involving caches and/or paging.  `2**28`  is a big enough array that these memory issues become important.

Answer (score 1):

with your `n=28` the times I get (with similar order to your results):

```
In [436]: %%timeit
     ...: test1 = test.reshape(n*[2])
     ...: test1 = np.moveaxis(test1, np.arange(n), perm1)
     ...: test1 = test1.reshape(2**n)
     ...: 
     ...: 
23 s ± 239 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [437]: %%timeit
     ...: test1 = test.reshape(n*[2])
     ...: test1 = np.moveaxis(test1, np.arange(n), perm2)
     ...: test1 = test1.reshape(2**n)
     ...: 
     ...: 
11.5 s ± 22.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [438]: %%timeit
     ...: test1 = test.reshape(n*[2])
     ...: test1 = np.moveaxis(test1, np.arange(n), perm3)
     ...: test1 = test1.reshape(2**n)
     ...: 
     ...: 
719 ms ± 28.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The 3 permuted orders are:

reversed:

```
perm1
Out[428]: 
array([27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11,
       10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0])
```

two blocks switched

```
perm2
Out[429]: 
array([15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,  0,  1,  2,  3,
        4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], dtype=int32)
```

first axis moved to the end:

```
perm3
Out[430]: 
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
       18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,  0], dtype=int32)
```

The last `reshape` is just `np.ravel()`.

All cases produce a `view` in the `moveaxis`, followed by a `copy` for the `ravel`.

strides for the 4 cases are:

```
In [446]: test1 = test.reshape(n*[2])
     ...: np.array(test1.strides)
Out[446]: 
array([536870912, 268435456, 134217728,  67108864,  33554432,  16777216,
         8388608,   4194304,   2097152,   1048576,    524288,    262144,
          131072,     65536,     32768,     16384,      8192,      4096,
            2048,      1024,       512,       256,       128,        64,
              32,        16,         8,         4])

In [447]: test1 = test.reshape(n*[2])
     ...: np.array(np.moveaxis(test1, np.arange(n), perm1).strides)
Out[447]: 
array([        4,         8,        16,        32,        64,       128,
             256,       512,      1024,      2048,      4096,      8192,
           16384,     32768,     65536,    131072,    262144,    524288,
         1048576,   2097152,   4194304,   8388608,  16777216,  33554432,
        67108864, 134217728, 268435456, 536870912])

In [448]: test1 = test.reshape(n*[2])
     ...: np.array(np.moveaxis(test1, np.arange(n), perm2).strides)
Out[448]: 
array([    65536,     32768,     16384,      8192,      4096,      2048,
            1024,       512,       256,       128,        64,        32,
              16,         8,         4, 536870912, 268435456, 134217728,
        67108864,  33554432,  16777216,   8388608,   4194304,   2097152,
         1048576,    524288,    262144,    131072])

In [449]: test1 = test.reshape(n*[2])
     ...: np.array(np.moveaxis(test1, np.arange(n), perm3).strides)
Out[449]: 
array([        4, 536870912, 268435456, 134217728,  67108864,  33554432,
        16777216,   8388608,   4194304,   2097152,   1048576,    524288,
          262144,    131072,     65536,     32768,     16384,      8192,
            4096,      2048,      1024,       512,       256,       128,
              64,        32,        16,         8])
```

Those are all the same step sizes, but just reordered as predicted by the perms.

### analysis

`reshape/ravel` has to take the reordered version, and traverse the values in the order specified by the strides, iterating with the smallest first.  Someone else with a better sense of processor caching etc, may be able to explain this better, but different orders can take different times.  The size is large enough that memory access times, with cashes and pages, can vary.

In sum, I don't think it's so much a matter of what `np.reshape` does, but more a matter of how long it takes to traverse memory in various orders.

As shown in my comments I first thought the big difference was in view vs copy.  But now I see all cases involve a copy.  It just that some dimension mix takes longer to traverse than others.  You'd have to dig a lot deeper than the `reshape` function itself to understand what's going on.  It involves the inner most workings of multidimensional arrays, and in particular the meaning and use of the `strides`.

My presentation would be more compact if you didn'tuse such a large `n`.  I first tried `n=5`, but for that the `ravel` step took less time than the `moveaxis`.  I suspect there's an intermediate size where the perm order doesn't make much difference.  Ignoring caching and paging issues, strided multidimensional arrays should be able access any order of dimensions in about equal time - such as if ravel times are on the order of a ms.